# Fixing "ambiguous use of" compiler error in swift

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, decoder

As part of my `SingleValueDecodingContainer`, I tried to make all `FixedWidthInteger` types use the same decoding method, however this leads to an "ambiguous use of" error in my `Bool` decoder that I don't know how to fix (*Bools are encoded as Int8 in this format*). Here is the affected code :

```swift
class SingleValueContainer : SingleValueDecodingContainer {
        var storage : Data = Data()
        
        var codingPath: [CodingKey]
        
        init(from data : Data, codingPath : [CodingKey] = []) {
            self.codingPath = codingPath
            self.storage = data
        }
        
        func decode(_ type: Bool.Type) throws -> Bool {
            guard let value = try? decode(Int8.self) else { // Ambiguous use of 'decode'
                let context = DecodingError.Context(
                    codingPath: self.codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "Could not decode UInt8 representation of boolean"
                )
                throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, context)
            }
            
            if value == 1 {
                return true
            } else if value == 0 {
                return false
            } else {
                let context = DecodingError.Context(
                    codingPath: self.codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "Incorrect value for UInt8 representation of boolean : \(value)"
                )
                throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)
            }
        }

        
        func decode<T: FixedWidthInteger>(_ type : T.Type) throws -> T {
            guard storage.count == type.bitWidth / 8 else {
                let context = DecodingError.Context(
                    codingPath: self.codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "Invalid number of bytes, expected \(type.bitWidth) instead of \(storage.count)"
                )
                throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)
            }
            
            return T(data : storage)
        }
    }
```

Do I have to make separate methods for all `FixedWidthInteger` types which call the generic one, or is there a way to fix with the error without doing that ?

---

Here is also the extension I made for `FixedWidthInteger` to initialise them from `Data` and `[UInt8]`, as I think it is necessary to understand the code above :

```swift
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    init(bytes : [UInt8]) {
        self.init(
            bigEndian : bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
                 ($0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: Self.self, capacity: 1) { $0 })
            }.pointee
        )
    }
    
    init(data : Data) {
        self.init(bytes : Array(data))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most FixedWidthInteger conforming types already implement Decodable. It's possible that the default implementation isn't what you want, but you can't change it.

If the default implementation works for you, you can get rid of your `decode<T: FixedWidthInteger>`.

If you want a different way of reading these, you need a different name for `decode<T: FixedWidthInteger>` so there's no ambiguity about which you mean. For example, you can rename it `read`:

```
func read<T: FixedWidthInteger>(_ type : T.Type) throws -> T { ... }
```

And then change your `decode` line to:

```
guard let value = try? read(Int8.self) else {
```

Comment: The issue being that I will then have every ‘’’decode’’’ override that takes a ‘’’FixedWidthInteger’’’ type be a one-liner that calls read, which isn’t very elegant. But it looks I don’t really have a choice

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it ! Look at my answer for details

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted this as a comment, then deleted it, but I think it is the right answer :
The reason it doesn't work is that I also had another generic `decode` override, that is required by the protocol :

```swift
func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type) throws -> T where T : Decodable {
    <#code#> // I haven't implemented this one yet, pretend there's code here
}
```

Which means that to resolve the **ambiguous** call, the generic for `FixedWidthInteger` must instead be for `FixedWidthInteger & Decodable` :

```swift
func decode<T: FixedWidthInteger & Decodable>(_ type : T.Type) throws -> T {
    guard storage.count == type.bitWidth / 8 else {
        let context = DecodingError.Context(
            codingPath: self.codingPath,
            debugDescription: "Invalid number of bytes, expected \(type.bitWidth) instead of \(storage.count)"
        )
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)
    }
            
    return T(data : storage)
}
```

And now everything works !